# How to develop intuition for writing claim?

Tags: claims, claim-construction

I've seen many patent claim examples, and I've tried to write some myself, but each time it feels like I cannot adequately describe/articulate the invention to the level that is needed for the patent office, or that similar to the actual claim. How does one become "good" at this; is it just practice over and over? Also, I know law/writing is fluid, but any buzzwords or formulas that I could use in writing claims? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One on-line resource is [Patent Drafting for Beginners: A prelude to patent claim drafting](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2016/10/29/patent-drafting-beginners-prelude-patent-claim-drafting/id=74332/) at ipwatchdog. The "bible" of the mechanics of claim drafting is Faber on Mechanics of Patent Claim Drafting. It is about $500 on Amazon. You might find a version from a couple of years ago for sale somewhere. And Patent it Yourself would be a good start.

One exercise I did when I started was to try to write a claim for something simple that I was pretty sure was patented and then to look up the actual patent. My first try was on Apple's magnetic power cable/connector on Apple laptops.

As an aside, European claim drafting is very very different from U.S. claim drafting.

Answer (score 2):

Practice, sure. Someone correcting the claims would help though ..

You could try the old european patent attorney exam questions pertaining to claim analysis and design. There are courses and such too.

It's not exactly easy to learn on your own in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I am a layman too. I found Hal Milton's book to be a great resource:

A Blueprint Derived from Appellate Opinions for Building a Patent Application: Patent Preparation in Six Steps to Produce the Highest Skilled and Most Efficient Patent Attorneys [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1512177016/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_Uv5JCb0YDCZQE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1512177016)